# Restrict the scope of functions in JavaScript ( Slider Use Case )?

Tags: javascript, restriction, restrict

In the following script, the code works when there is a slider, but when the number of sliders on a page is more than one, the next sliders do not work.

How can this script be changed when we have more than one slider on the page so that each slider **" Draggable Feature "** works separately and does not overlap?

What changes are needed to make this code **"Draggable feature"** work separately for each slider?

How can I handle this with " **querySelectorAll** " and " **forEach** " ?

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.items');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const walk = (x - startX) * 3; //scroll-fast
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
});
```

```css
.items,
.items_1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  background: green;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  will-change: transform;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;

  margin: 2rem auto;
  border: 3px solid violet;

}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 150px;
  margin: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>


<body>

  <div class="items">

    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>

  </div>


  <div class="items">

    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>

  </div>

  <div class="items">

    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>

  </div>


  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Apparently your code is only handling a single slider, so you can hardly expect more than one slider to work :) You have to put your slider manager in a class and create an instance for each slider you want to control.

Comment: @Qualima This website is not a free "fix your code" service. It's a database of Q&A topics that will help both current and future readers. You should learn JS first and then if you have conceptual questions, search for them on SO and if a topic does not exist yet (highly unlikely) make a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I handle this with " querySelectorAll " and " forEach " ?

Just put your code that declares the state variables and attaches the event handlers to *one* slider into such a loop:

```js
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.items');
for (const slider of sliders) {
  let isDown = false;
  let startX;
  let scrollLeft;

  slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    isDown = true;
    slider.classList.add('active');
    startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
  });
  slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    isDown = false;
    slider.classList.remove('active');
  });
  slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    isDown = false;
    slider.classList.remove('active');
  });
  slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    if (!isDown) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    const walk = (x - startX) * 3; //scroll-fast
    slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
  });
}
```

```css
.items {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  background: green;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  will-change: transform;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;

  margin: 2rem auto;
  border: 3px solid violet;

}
.items.active {
  border-color: blue;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 150px;
  margin: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>


<body>

  <div class="items">

    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>

  </div>


  <div class="items">

    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>

  </div>

  <div class="items">

    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>
    <div class="item "></div>

  </div>


  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```